# Why doesn't 'onclick' work when html is sent through php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There is a javascript in my page that loads a PHP script into a div every second. This PHP is supposed to run a  SQL query that loads data from a database.

Here is an extract of the PHP

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $starttime = $row['start_time'];
        $module = $row['module'];
        $item = $row['item'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['start_time'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['module'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['item'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['accepted'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['end_time'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><button id='btnaccept' onclick='acceptBtn()'>ACCEPT</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
```

And here is the Javascript

```
<script>
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    (function () {
     $("#dataDisplay").load("updatedb.php"); //Load the content into the div
    }), 1000);
</script>
```

As you can see, the last table data is a button that runs a Javascript function

```
 <script>
function acceptBtn() {
    window.alert("Accepted");
}
</script>
```

But unfortunately, clicking this button won't run the function. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what is the error in console

Comment: Is the button inside a <form>? In that case, it will do a submit too. Also, you're echoing an ID with a constant value in a loop; you should look into that.

Comment: Add the `type` attribute to your button: `type="button"`.

Comment: do you actually mean to load the html every second? or just once, as with setTimeout?

Comment: the button is not inside a form. It is just inside a table.
The table is reloaded every second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set listener:

```
echo "<td><button id='btnaccept'>ACCEPT</button></td>";
```

.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnaccept', acceptBtn);

function acceptBtn(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.alert("Accepted");
}
```